Generation time in stable cascade vs stable diffusion
According to the docs, Stable Cascade is meant to be faster than SD due to its architecture. However, when trying out using Python on my local machine, the results seem to be opposite. I am using a macOS (along with my GPU)
device = torch.device('mps')
pipe = pipe.to(device)

and here are example results:
Time taken to generate 1 image (including loading the pre-trained model):
Stable Diffusion: 51 secs
Stable Cascade: 230 seconds
Time taken to generate 1 image (excluding loading the model):
Stable Diffusion: 35 secs
Stable Cascade: 152 seconds
Caching: Is it possible that the time keeps reducing the future runs due to some sort of caching? If so, is it possible to avoid caching for the purpose of testing?
I am using these models:
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5",
    torch_dtype=torch.float32,
    use_safetensors=True,
)

pipe = StableCascadeCombinedPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-cascade", variant="bf16", torch_dtype=torch.float32)

